# Simplest way to do Lazy Loading with LINQ2SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, optimization, lazy-loading

I have a read-only database, so I am turning off ObjectTracking (thus implicitly turning off DeferredLoading).

I wish to do lazy loading and not use LoadWith<>.

What is the simplest way to explicitly tell Linq to go and lazy fetch a relation just before I need the data itself.

For example: a simple dbml
[image]

If I have the following code:

```
  TestDbDataContext context = new TestDbDataContext(Settings.Default.TestersConnectionString);
  context.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;

  var result = context.Employees.ToList();
  foreach (var employee in result)
  {
    // HERE Should load gift list
    foreach (var gift in employee.Gifts)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(gift.Name);
    }
  }
```

I know I can write a full query again, but I hope we can find together a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fighting the system... 2 thoughts:

- if you know you need the other data (nested `foreach`), why wouldn't you want to use `LoadWith`? That is pretty-much the text-book use case
- since you (from post) know that object tracking is required for lazy loading, why not just enable object tracking; data-contexts should usually be considered "units of work" (i.e. short-lived), so this isn't likely to hurt much in reality.

See the official replies [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=295753) for why these two options (object tracking and deferred loading) are linked.

Comment: The code you see is a much simplified version of my real code. My code first assumed LoadWith, now I'm trying to optimize and lazy load instead of eager load (because of performance), so just before I really need the data I want want to load it. It may really leave the scope of the datacontext...

Comment: and data will be passed through the application.

Comment: Are you actually suer, from profiling, that ObjectTracking is causing you a problem. Given your requirements, I'd just enable it. Personally, though, I like a repository pattern with no lazy loading - my repository fetches data (or updates data) within a method and then has nothing to do with it...

Comment: The problem is that if I've got plenty of relations (I've ended with 17 LoadWith<> statements) loading a single entity can take much time. what should I do?

Comment: BTW about repository pattern. Do you consider this article as valid guide for implementing with Linq2Sql ? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/linqrepository.aspx

Comment: I'd argue that needing 17 sets of external data means that you aren't doing controlled data access - i.e. methods that do 1 clear thing. My thoughts are: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/pragmatic-linq.html

Comment: Re that article - I lean away from returning IEnumerable<T>/IQueryable<T> from repo methods, as it means you can't unit/integration test it properly. If I call a DAL method, I want it to do its job and step away... YMMV, however.

Comment: Read you blog post, it sounds reasonable to me.
It is possible for you to publish a small example of how to structure it correctly? I would eternally grateful:)

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that today - but essentially my repository methods return homogeneous data (or very tightly coupled data such as header/line) *only*. No IEnumerable<T>/IQueryable<T>/Expression<T> on the interface, and no lazy loading. The navigation properties are internal, so usable at the

Comment: repository, but not by the caller - allows you to write interesting queries while retaining purity of the methods. Spanning queries (search etc) return a bespoke "FooResult" type (list/array-of) rather than trying to return the regular entities.

Comment: For all I know I'm going crazy/er/ but it seems to work pretty well. The repository is then a black box, and can be tested and mocked very robustly. Lazy loading etc doesn't allow this.

Comment: What do you think on that approach?
  class Repository<T> where T : class
  {
    public List<T> Find(Func<T, bool> expr)
    {
      using (context = new TestDbDataContext()
      {
        context.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
        return context.GetTable<T>().Where(expr).ToList();
      }}}

Comment: You'll need Expression<Func<T,bool>> (not just Func<T,bool>) to get that to work - which means that your repository is not at the mercy of the caller; you a: can't prove the expression is usable (not all operations are mapped), and b: can't profile/optimise it. Which is why *personally* I prefer ...

Comment: ... a closed repository - i.e. my Find method might have discreet arguments for common search patterns, but that is defined by the interface. It also means that the repository is not LINQ-specific, so you can still provide any implementation under the hood. This view comes, in part, from having ...

Comment: ... to support apps that tend to live for a while, with re-use. If you are writing a standalone, specific app, then use whatever works.

Comment: If an entity is very different from it counterparts than you will end up writing a different repository for each entity. Right ?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't have a Repository<T>, if that is what you mean... a single repository interface might support a few closely related entities. A single repository class *could* implement multiple repository interfaces (although whether it *should* is another theme). It comes down to "aggregates".

Comment: I like repositories returning IQueryable as query can be further adjusted along the way (specification pattern etc.)
The repository's purpose is to wrap data storage semantics (linq2sql or whatever else you're using) to aggregate entities defined in the code.

Comment: @Eran - while useful, it makes it impossible to test caller and callee in isolation, and impossible to profile / optimize.

Comment: @Mark why impossible to test? you can return IQueryable on top of some mock test data (or, you can abstract IDataContext and implement a real&fake data contexts).

Comment: Because you need to factor in the translation to the backend storage model. Not all expressions can be translated to TSQL/ESQL/HQL (depending on the API) - indeed, something as simple as Single() works differently between EF and LINQ-to-SQL. Unit tests would typically use LINQ-to-Objects, but that..

Comment: ..means nothing if your actual repository has to talk to a database or external resource. Hence you cannot do unit testing (or rather: it is meaningless). If you expose IQueryable<T> or Expression on the repository API, *only* full integration tests are valid.

Comment: I see your point... Its certainly a design consideration. I built a Services layer on top of the repositories that are in charge of all the interaction with the repositories (program works against the services and not directly with repositories). The services is where unit testing is important...

Comment: Marc, I've just stumbled on Ayende's post on repository what do you think in correspondence to your own post.

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/17/repository-is-the-new-singleton.aspx

Comment: @ArielBH - I agree with some of the issues raised, but **especially** with the current state of LINQ-to-SQL vs EF, I genuinely like the abstraction offered, and the mock aspects. As always, the needs of specific projects will be important, but for now at least, abstraction behind an interface is my preferred route. Not *at least* until 4.0 (maybe one of the service packs), but *at some point* I'd like to have the option to switch to EF without a complete rewrite of my higher layers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LazyList:
http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/lazy-loading-with-the-lazylist/

Comment: Yeah, I know about that one. But this one demands major rewrites of the generated entities and queries.

Comment: From experience, having your own data model beats counting on Linq2Sql... (too many advantages to list here)

Comment: Worth thought but irrelevant.

Comment: Havent played much with the Linq2Sql autogenerated class but maybe you can get it to NOT generate the Gifts property and then add a partial class to Employee and define that property yourself (using IQueryable rather than EntitySet or whatever Linq2Sql uses)